# Evaluating in PARI/GP the Fourier coefficients of the j -invariant?

Tags: math-software, modular-forms

Which PARI-commands evaluates the q-expansion, i.e. the Fourier coefficents of the modular j-invariant?

**Note**. ellj(x) computes single values of j; and mfcoefs(-,-) computes coefficents. But mfcoefs(ellj,8) is not accepted.

Comment: Maybe better answers would be obtained in a forum on PARI/GP, as opposed to a forum on mathematics.

Answer (score 0):

I learned: PARI expects the function as defined by its **mapping rule**

F = x -> ellj(x);

V = laurentseries(F,8);

print("q-expansion of modular j-invariant: ", V);

Output:

q-expansion of modular j-invariant: x^-1 + 744 + 196884*x + 21493760*x^2 + 864299970*x^3 + 20245856256*x^4 + 333202640600*x^5 + 4252023300096*x^6 + 44656994071935*x^7 + 401490886656000*x^8 + O(x^9)